# Angular ng-model bind to element name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a syntax that will allow me to use ng-model to bind to a scope property with the same name as the element I am binding to?

So, in the following example:

```
<input name="myinputname" type="text" ng-model="?" />
```

is there something I can use as the ng-model value that will resolve to "myinputname", without requiring me to hard-code it?

Comment: You can make your own smartInput directive that handles the stuff:  <smartInput name="myName" />

Comment: no simple syntax , if you have a lot of elements can create a directive for them that lets you share attributes. Should note though...is highly highly advised to make sure you have a **dot** in `ng-model` so it is object refrence not a primitive

Comment: I am trying to add the ng-model attribute to an input rendered by server side code (ASP.NET MVC to be precise).  Ideally, I would add the ng-model attribute and it would default to the field name generated by the server code.

Answer (score 2):

If you could add the `ng-model` from the server side, it will have a better performance.

But in case you really want to do it in client-side, you could write a custom directive that will add the `ng-model` automatically at compile time like this:

```
app.directive('myModel', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true, // these terminal and a high priority will stop all other directive from being compiled at first run
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('ngModel', attrs.name); // set value of ng-model to be the same as the name attribute
      attrs.$set('myModel', null); // remove itself to avoid a recusion

      $compile(element)(scope); // begin compiling other directives
    }
  };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myinputname" my-model />
```

after the first compilation it will automatically become:

```
<input type="text" name="myinputname" ng-model="myinputname" />
```

**Plunker example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hBQQMDTr6cYtHzFvoAaQ?p=preview